# Apply Adjacent sibling combinator in BEM

Tags: css, bem

I would like to insert the following plane css code in my BEM structure. But for some reason the before psuedo class isnt appearing in the DOM tree. 
Anyone know how to apply this CSS code into BEM?

CSS:

```
li + li:before {
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  .icon(@unicode: '\f105'; @iconset: 'FontAwesome');
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__item">
    <a class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__link" href="#" title="text">
        <span class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__text">link1</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__item">
    <a class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__link" href="#" title="text">
        <span class="mod-breadcrumbContainer__text">link2</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this:

    &__item + __item:before {
      height: 22px;
      line-height: 22px;
      .icon(@unicode: '\f105'; @iconset: 'FontAwesome');
      font-size: 22px;
      opacity: 0.2;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;

Comment: If anything, you would want `&__item + &__item:before` …

Comment: that wont work. But I have already founded a solution: &__item { + li:before {...} } Thanks anyway for your response

Comment: That would apply this for _any_ LI that follows a `.mod-breadcrumbContainer__item` element, no matter whether it itself has that class as well or not. (Might not matter in most situations, but is still something different.)

Comment: In this case that will target any LI inside the .mod-breadcrumbContainer except the first one, which is fine to me.